# Firebase Web redirect user to login page

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Trying to simply redirect the users who are authenticated to `home.html` and those who are not to `login.html` via Firebase.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (user) {
    console.log('SIGNED IN');
    window.location.href = "home.html"; // <-- This is not good...
  } else {
    console.log('NOT SIGNED IN');
  }
});
```

Everyone says to use this bit of code, and it does work to keep track if the user is logged in, but if I put that line inside the **if check** it will just cause an infinite loop constantly redirecting the browser to the home page once the user is authenticated.

Is there something simple I missed?

Answer (score 0):

The code you're showing will redirect *any* time the auth state changes to show there's a user present.  And that will trigger in *any* page being loaded, as the SDK doesn't know ahead of the page load if the user is logged in.  The SDK has to wait for an init to complete in order to trigger the listener.  So, it sounds like that's not what you want.

What you'll have to do is define specifically *at what point* in your app that you want a redirect to happen, and make sure that condition and timing is met before you redirect.

Comment: Is there not a simple check I can add to the top of the `index.html` page or any other page that redirects to either the home page or login page? I want the code to be fired whenever anyone visits any page or else a user could just manually type in the address and gain access to the home page without being authenticated? Or am I confused.

Comment: No, the user will always appear to be logged out at the very beginning of any page, because the SDK hasn't been able to initialize and check that any tokens are not expired.  You have to use the listener to figure the first moment when it's known that the user is *actually* logged in.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do then. My index.html landing page is actually a page for signing up. I want to redirect the already logged in users to home.html when they land on my index.html. Or am I just going about this all wrong?

Comment: Solved it. Just moved that code above to only fire in on the login page instead of on all pages causing the loop.